# Modify _layout for different users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my App I have navbar with menu. In menu I have 3 dropdowns.

- public
- for normal users
- for admins

Access is restricted but menus are visible for all. I want to hide unnecessary element for normal and public(anynymous) users.

***for identyfication I'm using windows login names***

To get a user role I'm asking database and query returns if user is normal user or admin.

My solution:

```
public bool CheckIfAdmin(string login)
    {
        bool admin = false;
        EquipmentEntities db = new EquipmentEntities();
        Tuple<string, string> credentials = GetName(login);
        int RoleId = db.Users.Where(w => w.Name == credentials.Item1).Where(w => w.Surname == credentials.Item2).Select(s => s.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
        if(RoleId==1)
        {
            admin = true;
        }
        return admin;
    }
```

and nearly same code for for checking if User

in methods:

```
if(CheckIfAdmin(login)){
ViewBag.Role=1;
}
else if(CheckIfUser(login)){
    ViewBag.Role=2;
}
```

and finally in layout:

```
 @if (ViewBag.Role==1)
        {
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                //MEnu
            </ul>
          </li>
         }
```

and nearly same code for second dropdown I want to hide.
This is working but I at this moment I need to put checks for role in each method. Its large amount of redundant code. Can anyone suggest me how to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your roles is static, because you check `if(RoleId==1)` so that user is admin. I think you can define roles like `enum`.

```
public enum UserRole
        {
            User = 1,
            Manager = 2,
            Admin = 3,
            //SuperAdmin...etc.
        }
```

Create base controller, add CurrentUser property. And when action execute take current user.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
   {
      protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
         CurrentUser = db.GetLoggedUserFromDatabase();  // to use in controller
         ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;             // to use in views
      }

      public User CurrentUser { get; set; }   
   }
```

Finally your controller implements `BaseController`:

```
 public class AnyController : BaseController 
{
       //in every action you have current user's details.
       //Already you know current users role. you can use it. for example:
       public ActionResult AnyAction()
       {
         if(CurrentUser != null)   //if user logged
         {
           if (CurrentUser.Role == (int)UserRole.Admin) 
           {
              //user is admin
           }   
         }      
       }
}
```

In views you can use  `ViewBag.CurrentUser`. Cast it first then check role as in controller.