# Navigation pulled from database and displayed in master layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a web application in ASP.NET MVC. When the user logs in, I want to retrieve his navigation (varies between user accounts) and his information from the database, and keep the info between controllers.

I'm displaying the navigation in `_Layout.cshtml` so I'm wondering best practices to pull the navigation and other user info from the database and storing it between controllers. This information is only retrieved once and stored through-out the user "log-in session".

What is the ideal solution? Should I create a `BaseController` which other controllers inherit and put my logic in the constructor and put the info in a `global ViewBag`? Or should I use the `Session` object in the `Login` method? Or should I create a static method and call it directly from _Layout.cshtml?

What should I do? I want to do this globally once, so I don't have to do this in each controller action.

Comment: Yes, you are in right way to my mind. I posted an answer here like your idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21883256/1534785 .Maybe it can help

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Then make a singleton so it doesn't retrieve the info from DB each time an action is executed and uses the in memory object.

Comment: The BaseController and singleton is not working as I expected, because the controller only has a lifetime through the request, so the object is always null and recreated (pulled from the database). Is this something I could use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343899/how-to-cache-data-in-a-mvc-application

Comment: No doubt, you should call db method in every request. If you want to call one time, you can use Session, Cookie etc.